# is anything less than n is log n?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Consider there are two solutions for a problem.

1. executes in n/2 times ie. if n = 100 then it executes in 50 times
2. executes in sqrt of n times ie. if n = 100 then it executes in 10 times.

Are both the solutions can be called as **O(log N)** ?

if so, then there is huge difference between sqrt of N and N/2.

if we can't say O(log N) then can we say it is N ?

But the problem is the difference rate between these two. By the below image the algorithm should come in either of these thing, under which these solutions will come ?

[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Neither of there two is log N.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski then how to call those ? O(N) ?

Comment: You first case is still *O(n)* (liner multipliers are factored out). The second is *O(* sqrt *(n))*. Neither is *O(* log *n)*.

Comment: First is linear (polynomial with exponent 1), the second is square-root complexity (polynomial with exponent 0.5).

Comment: Can anyone look back the edited question and suggest something ?

Comment: It's like asking *"is anything smaller than a 100 always the same as 10? what if I have a 50, is it 10?"* - no, there are infinite possible complexities, you can have n*log^2(n), or n*log(logn)), etc..
In this case, Richard (and others) already explained the complexities you've brought.

Comment: It's a matter of notation. Formally, both can be considered to be in `O(n)`, since `O(n) > O(sqrt(n)) > O(log(n))`. As the limiting case, all fall within `O(n)`, but neither fall in `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the three cases.

1. Executes `n/2` times. That means each time we increase n by a factor of 100, the execution time increases by a factor of 100.
2. Executes `sqrt(n)` times. That means each time we increase n by a factor of 100, the execution time increases by a factor of 10.
3. Executes `log(n)` times. That means each time we increase n by a factor of 100, the execution time increases by a constant amount.

No, these three things aren't even close to the same. The first is much worse than the second. The third is much better than the second.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them is `O(logn)`

Here is an example of `O(logn)`, [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

The best algorithm is the best algorithm for the data that you have.  If you don't know what data you have, consider massively large amounts of data, say n= 1 billion.  Would you choose O(31623), or O(5000000000)?  Graph the comparison and find where your data size is.

If your dataset was n=4, then either algorithm is identical.  If you get in to the details, it may actually take longer for the sqrt(n) algorithm due to the operations it conducts.

You can have O(1) which is the fastest.  One such example is looking up in a hash map, but your memory size may suffer.  So you should consider space constraints as well as time constraints.

You are also misunderstanding and overanalyzing complexity classification.  O(n) algorithms are not algorithms that execute with exactly n operations.  Any constant multiplier does not affect the Order of the classification.  What is important is the grown of the number of operations when the problem grows.  Consider two search algorithms.

```
A) Scan a sorted list sequentially from index 0 to (n-1) to find the number.

B) Scan a sorted list from from index 0 to (n-1), skipping by 2, and backtracking if necessary.
```

Clearly A takes at most n operations, and B takes n/2+1 operations.  Yet they are both O(n).  You can say algorithm B is faster, but I might run it on my machine which is twice as fast.  So complexity is a general class, one isn't supposed to need to be overly finicky on the details of the operation.

If you were trying to develop a better algorithm, it would be much more useful to search for one with a better complexity class, than one with slightly fewer operations.